# How to return redux state to initial state?

Tags: javascript, state, redux

I'm having surprisingly difficult time figuring this out, essentially I'm trying to set state to initial state, so far I tried:

```
// -- Initial state ------------------------------------------------------------
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  search: {
    listings: []
  },
  listings: []
}

// -- Story structure for story editor -----------------------------------------
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return { ...state, INITIAL_STATE }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

this just adds initial state to existing one

---

```
case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return { ...state, state = INITIAL_STATE }
```

this returns error

---

```
case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return { ...state, state: INITIAL_STATE }
```

this is adding initial state to existing one gain

---

```
case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return { ...state, search: { listings:[] }, listings: [] }
```

This works, but I start getting weird mutation errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to reset state completely, just return the *value* of `INITIAL_STATE`:

```
export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return {
                 search: {
                     listings: []
                 },
                 listings: []
             };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the `INITIAL_STATE` in a single place.  Change the initial state creator to a function:

```
function get_INITIAL_STATE => {
  return { search: {
               listings: []
           },
           listings: []
         }
}

export default function(state = get_INITIAL_STATE(), action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return get_INITIAL_STATE();
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason returning INITIAL_STATE returns it how it was before

Comment: While the updated answer will work, the correct idiomatic approach is Jiri Frnous', below.

Answer (score 4):

The proposed solution of Anders is right, but has potential problem with immutables. This generates always new object.

```
case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
    return { ...INITIAL_STATE };
```

Answer (score 3):

**Look at Jiri Fornous solution instead, as this will mutate your data.**

An even easier way is to just return INITIAL_STATE.

```
case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return INITIAL_STATE;
```