# Resetting store to initialState is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a ReactJS app using Redux and redux-storage

I needed a button that can reset the store to its initial state, so I wrote my reducer like this:

```
const initialState={...}

export default function ProfilationSelectReducer (state=initialState, action){
 switch(action.type){
 ...
 case ProfilationSelectActionTypes.CLEAR_STORE:{

            return initialState
        }
 ...
 }
}
```

Now, this code WORKS in a page of the app but in other pages it looks like the initialState is *changing* (despite being a const) resulting in not clearing the state.

Any thought about this behavior? If more information is needed I'll be happy to share it with you

Comment: Can you share the code (how you are calling the clear store action) and console output of your state on the pages where this is not working?

Comment: It's worth noting that a variable declared as const is still mutable.  Const only prevents an object from being reassigned (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Comment: Have you tried using the deepFreeze library on the const variable to see if your reducer functions are pure?

Comment: Also, just as a general observation: you are writing an extremely outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux here that is about 4x the amount of code. If you are just learning Redux, please follow an up-to-date tutorial like the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts). Also, please read up on [modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today). You should not need to write switch..case reducers in 2023.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out following this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35477308/8608574

I changed the declaration of my initialState to a function. This is my code now:

```
function getInitialState(){
 return{...}
}

export default function ProfilationSelectReducer (state=getInitialState(), action){
 switch(action.type){
 ...
 case ProfilationSelectActionTypes.CLEAR_STORE:{
        return getInitialState()
    }
 ...

 }
}
```

Thanks everybody for your help

Comment: There is a good chance that you have to do this because some of your other code actually mutated the `state` object instead of doing an immutable update. With this, you are essentially working around a bug that still exists somewhere in your code base, but isn't fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Those other pages are likely calling an action updating the store on load. use redux dev tool to see how your store is being updated. i can't recommend it enough, saves tone of work and time.